# How do I show/allow yammer user input on embed topic feed

Tags: yammer

I'm attempting to embed a Yammer feed on a webpage to present all posts based on a **topic (hashtag).**
At the same time, I want the ability for users to **create new Yammer posts** at the top of the widget.

From all combinations of settings, I cannot find the ability to do both.
Users seemingly can post when "feedType" is [blank] or "all", but not "topic".

Is it possible to *both* display a Topic feed and allow the user to create a new post?

Settings for Topic feed:

```
yam.connect.embedFeed({
  container: '#yammer-feed',
  network: 'company.com',
  feedType: 'topic',
  feedId: '1308',         // #yam hashtag
  config: {
    defaultGroupId: 'all',
    header: true
  }
});
```

Settings enabling Post ability

```
yam.connect.embedFeed({
  container: '#yammer-feed',
  network: 'company.com',
  feedType: '',           // now blank - user post input appears
  feedId: '1308',         // seemingly worthless w/ this feedType
  config: {
    defaultGroupId: 'all',
    header: true
  }
});
```

Can I have both?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you don't see the ability to add a new post when you have a topic feed is that Yammer doesn't have a way to automatically tag the new post. The posts have to exist in a group (even All Network is a group) and thus just putting a topic wouldn't be enough.

So sorry that there isn't a way to do what you are looking for - have you thought about using OpenGraph to have a comment feed in addition to the topic feed perhaps?